# Remove bokeh logo from a list of figures

Tags: python, bokeh

You can easily remove Bokeh logo from a single figure doing the following:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models.tools import PanTool, SaveTool

p = figure()
p.line([1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 4, 3, 0])
p.toolbar.logo = None
p.tools = [SaveTool(), PanTool()]
show(p)
```

or just using `p.toolbar_location = None`

I, however, didn't manage to hide it when having multiple figures:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models.tools import PanTool, SaveTool
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, BoxZoomTool, WheelZoomTool, LassoSelectTool, BoxSelectTool, ResetTool, \
    PanTool, TapTool, SaveTool

tools = [PanTool(), BoxZoomTool(match_aspect=True), WheelZoomTool(), BoxSelectTool(),
         ResetTool(), TapTool(), SaveTool()]

figures = [figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=800,
                  tools=tools, output_backend="webgl", match_aspect=True) for i in range(2)]

figures[0].line([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 3, 0])
figures[0].toolbar.logo = None

figures[1].line([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 3, 0])
figures[1].toolbar.logo = None

show(gridplot([figures], merge_tools=True, sizing_mode='scale_height'))
```

I've also tried `figures.toolbar.logo = None` but of course it doesn't work as it's a list and it has no such attribute. How can i do that?

Comment: `figures[1].toolbar.logo = None` works for me. In general, `figure.toolbar.logo = None`  hides the logo of Bokeh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configured toolbar options to `gridplot` by passing a `toolbar_options` argument to gridplot:

```
grid = gridplot([figures], merge_tools=True, sizing_mode='scale_height', 
                toolbar_options=dict(logo=None))

show(grid)
```

This is documented in the [Reference Guide entry for `gridplot`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/layouts.html#bokeh.layouts.gridplot)

Comment: Is there also a way to make the tools bigger qua size? and a way to deselect the default behavior from "selected" to "not selected" of the first tool in each category? as for the above example, the "TapTool" is always selected when i run the code but i don't want it that way. is that solveable?

Comment: Toolbars have options for setting (initially) active tools, e.g. http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.Toolbar.active_drag These can go in the same dict.

Comment: Actually, it looks like this may not be implemented yet for grid plots: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4568

Answer (score 2):

`logo=None` didn't work for me. This css declaration did however:

```
<style>
.bk-logo {
    display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fig.toolbar.logo = None
```

It removes the logo.